# Retrieving a video from Documents Directory, but app cannot find location

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, video, core-data

I have implemented Core Data to save string formatted URLS in my application. These URLS are URLS of videos they have recorded.

I used core data because I want the video to still be available to them after they exit out of the app. I am able to save and retrieve the URLS. However, when i use them to get the video thumbnails it does not work.

Here is where I declare the video file location:

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let cropUniqueId = NSUUID().uuidString
    let outputPath = "\(documentsPath)/\(cropUniqueId).mov"
```

Then i convert it to a string and save the data to core data:

```
 arrayOfStringPaths.append(outputPath)
    stringOfArrayPaths = stringOfArrayPaths + arrayOfStringPaths.joined(separator: ",")
    saveData(arrayPath: stringOfArrayPaths)



 func saveData(arrayPath: String) {

    let savedVideo = VideoPath(context: context)
    savedVideo.fileLocations = arrayPath
    appDelegate.saveContext()
    print("Saved")

}
```

Everything so far works fine. It saves the URLS just as they are, i checked them with various print statements.

Now I retrieve the information when the user opens the app.

```
var data = [VideoPath]()

    func fetchSavedData() {
    do {
        data = try context.fetch(VideoPath.fetchRequest())


        for each in data {
            // I append each url to the array. 
            videosArray.append(URL(fileURLWithPath: each.fileLocations!))

            // They all print out correctly 
            print(each.fileLocations!)
        }

        for video in videosArray {
            print("This is in video array")
            // This prints out correctly as the URL i recorded earlier
            print(video) 

            // This is where everything messes up
            let thumbnail = getThumbnail(video)
            thumbnails.append(thumbnail)

        }

    } catch {
        print("There was an error")
    }

}
```

When i try to get the thumbnail of the video it gives me this error here:

> "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server., NSUnderlyingError=0x17064c330 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-802.0.53/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift

Comment: Have you verified that `getThumbnail` works on the initial URL when you're saving?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly

Comment: However, it seems that it can't find the URL

Comment: I think you're doing your URL setup incorrectly.

Comment: When i record the video, i can see the thumbnail and the video in my app perfectly fine. However when i exit out of the app it is gone. I'm sure the URLS are all fine, but what would you suggest?

Comment: It sounds like it's not being permanently saved. You're not keeping it in a cache or other temporary folder, right?

Comment: I did exactly what you told me to do in my last question. I saved it to the documents directory folder using a unique id string. I'm not keeping it in a cache as far as I know. I did a test of where i retrieve the URLS after closing the app, and they match the same exact URLs i recorded with.